# Process multiple AJAX or SOAP calls on an ordered array of objects

Tags: javascript, ajax

Each object has to trigger multiple AJAX calls in cascade (each request is called in the callback of the preceeding), but the order here matter. The first object must have completed all its requests before the next object starts his requests and so on.

Actually, in my code, all objects are processing their requests simultaneously even if I use a timeout in the waitForProcessFinish() function.

```
//object properties
function LayerQuery(objectDefinition) {
    this.class = "FilteredLayer";
    this.alias = objectDefinition["alias"];
    this.sourceLayerName = objectDefinition["sourceLayerName"];
    this.sourceTableName = objectDefinition["sourceTableName"];
    this.fieldName = objectDefinition["fieldName"];
    this.operator = objectDefinition["operator"];
    this.label = objectDefinition["label"];
    this.layerStyle = objectDefinition["layerStyle"];
    this.value = objectDefinition["value"];
    this.layerVisible = objectDefinition["layerVisible"];
    this.labelVisible = objectDefinition["labelVisible"];
    this.zoomMin = objectDefinition["zoomMin"];
    this.zoomMax = objectDefinition["zoomMax"];
    this.position = objectDefinition["position"];
    this.control = objectDefinition["control"];
    this.info = objectDefinition["info"];
    this.fieldsOrder = objectDefinition["fieldsOrder"];
    this.fields = [];
    this.baseLayer = objectDefinition["baseLayer"];
}

function LayerQueries(list) {
  this.queries = list;
}

LayerQueries.prototype.loadLayers = function(){
  for (i=0; i< this.queries.length; i++){
      this.queries[i].loading = true;
      this.queries[i].addFilteredLayer();
      this.queries[i].waitForProcessFinish(); //wait for object's requests done to start next object
  }
  this.waitForProcessesFinish(); // wait for all objects' requests done
}

LayerQuery.prototype.addFilteredLayer = function(){
  var query = this;
  $.soap({
  url: 'https://carto48dev.mels.gouv.qc.ca/pushnsee_4.8/services/MapService',
  method: 'addFilteredLayer',
  appendMethodToURL: false,
  data : {
      mapInstanceKey: mapKey,
      tablePath: this.sourceTableName,
      layerName: this.sourceLayerName,
      separators: { value: ["AND"]},
      fieldNames: { value: [this.fieldName]},
      operators: { value: [this.operator]},
      values: { value: [this.value]},
      int: 0
      },
  error: function(e){
      console.log("Error addFilteredLayer: " + query.sourceLayerName);
      query.loading = false;
   },
  success: function(soapResponse){
     query.getColumnDefinitions();
  }
  });
}

LayerQuery.prototype.getColumnDefinitions = function(){
  var query = this;
  $.soap({
    url: 'https://carto48dev.mels.gouv.qc.ca/pushnsee_4.8/services/GeobaseService',
    method: 'getColumnDefinitions',
    appendMethodToURL: false,
    data : {
      tablePath: this.sourceTableName,
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log("Error getColumnDefinitions: " + query.sourceLayerName);
        query.loading = false;
     },
    success: function(soapResponse){
      var columnsDef = JSON.parse(soapResponse.toJSON().Body.getColumnDefinitionsResponse.getColumnDefinitionsReturn.text);
      for (var i=0; i< columnsDef.length; i++){
        query.fields.push(columnsDef[i].name);
      }
      query.loading = false;
    }
  });
}

LayerQuery.prototype.waitForProcessFinish = function(){
  query = this;
  if (this.loading == false) {
    console.log("process finish")
    return;
  }else {
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log("waiting...");
       query.waitForProcessFinish();
    },100);
  }
}

LayerQueries.prototype.waitForProcessesFinish = function(){
  layerQueries = this;
  this.processesFinished = 0;
  for (i=0; i<this.queries.length; i++){
    if (this.queries[i].loading == false) {
      this.processesFinished += 1;
    }
  }
  if (this.processesFinished == this.queries.length){
    layerQueries.setVisibilities();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log("waiting again...");
       layerQueries.waitForProcessesFinish();
    },100);
  }
}

var queries = new LayerQueries([Mask_General_Query,Mask_Query,Cs_General_Query,Cs_Query,Mrc_General_Query,Mrc_Query,Mun_General_Query,Mun_Query,Org_FpAdulte_Query,Org_Sec_Query,Org_PrimSec_Query,Org_Primaire_Query]);

queries.loadLayers(); //trigger the ajax requests
```

Up Up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not block - it schedules its argument function for execution later, and immediately returns.  So when you call `waitForProcessFinish` it is returning immediately no matter what - hence the next AJAX is sent out before the first one has completed.

Instead, you can chain the function calls as callbacks:

```
LayerQueries.prototype.loadLayers = function(){
  var layerQueries = this;
  var list = this.queries;
  if (list.length > 0){
      list[0].addFilteredLayer(makeCallback(1));
  }
  function makeCallback(i){
      if (i < list.length){
         return function() { list[i].addFilteredLayer(makeCallback(i+1)); }
      } else {
         return function() { layerQueries.setVisibilities(); }
      }
  }
}

LayerQuery.prototype.addFilteredLayer = function(callback){
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
  success: function(soapResponse){
     query.getColumnDefinitions(callback);
  }
  });
}

LayerQuery.prototype.getColumnDefinitions = function(callback){
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    success: function(soapResponse){
      var columnsDef = JSON.parse(soapResponse.toJSON().Body.getColumnDefinitionsResponse.getColumnDefinitionsReturn.text);
      for (var i=0; i< columnsDef.length; i++){
        query.fields.push(columnsDef[i].name);
      }
      callback();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Im not sure to understand, `callback();` is not define anywhere

Comment: "callback" is a function passed as a parameter by loadLayers to addFilteredLayer, and then by addFilteredLayer to getColumnDefinitions.  Notice the new parameter in the header line of those functions.

Comment: this is working perfectly, thank you but something curious is hapening when I put a `callback();` in the error of the AJAX requests. If 3 of the objects return an error for a specific AJAX request, for the third I got an error in the console: TypeError: `callback is not a function`

Comment: in fact, the last object of the list got the callback is not a function error when calling callback() at the end of the processes

Comment: That happened because no arguments were given when loadLayers was called - it expected a function to call after all AJAX requests completed.  I've modified it so it no longer needs this, and instead automatically calls the function you had been calling in your waitForProcessesFinish function.

Comment: perfect! thank you very much, I have learned something important here.